# How to hide cmd.exe/console log of chromedriver in selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cmd, selenium-chromedriver

## How to hide cmd.exe/console log of chromedriver in selenium in python?

I tried:

```
driver.service.stop()
```

Full Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

print("Opening...")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.service.stop()
```

But it didn't close the console log/ cmd.exe

[image: See the console log image]

Comment: `Try driver.quit()`

Comment: @HaR it closes the chrome, not the console log...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @JeffC I clarified the specific problem, added additional details, also highlighted exactly what I need.....Whats difficult there to understand..?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot hide it completely in Chrome driver but you can suppress few and set minimum log level as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('log-level=2')
```

where log-level is

```
INFO = 0, 
WARNING = 1, 
LOG_ERROR = 2, 
LOG_FATAL = 3.
```

Comment: Why I cannot hide it completely...?

Comment: Also, I tried all four, `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
options.add_argument('--log-level=1')
options.add_argument('--log-level=2')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)`, but nothing changed....

Answer (score -1):

```
  #Combine this two options: 

  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument('--log-level=3')

  dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
  dc['loggingPrefs'] = {'driver': 'OFF', 'server': 'OFF', 'browser': 'OFF'}

  self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=dc, executable_path="C:\\path\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Some explanation about how this answers the question would help. You can use the [edit] link below the answer to supplement the content.