# Console Log/ cmd.exe not closing in chromedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to hide console log/cmd.exe (chromedriver.exe) but it is not hiding/closing..

I tried:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
options.add_argument('--log-level=1')
options.add_argument('--log-level=2')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

**Note:**
Using latest versions of Chrome and Chromedriver

Comment: Which version of Chrome and chromedriver you are using?

Comment: I am using latest versions of both, chrome and chromedriver...

Comment: To my knowledge you cannot hide the console log of chromedriver, in latest versions....

Comment: Hi, I think you have a ways to solve this:
1. Executing ```taskkill``` command using os.system()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide command prompt in Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654427/hide-command-prompt-in-selenium-chromedriver)