# url is not defined, in python and selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, undefined

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> url is not defined

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
url='https://www.yahoo.com'
current = driver.current_window_handle
driver.execute_script("window.open(url);") #New tab
new_window = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current][0] # Get new tab ID
driver.switch_to.window(new_window) # Switch to new tab
```

While running the above code it gave me error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> url is not defined

## Though url is define just 2 lines before..

Comment: And which line raised this error? Please provide full traceback.

Comment: The error is because the **javascript** variable `url` is not defined. How would the browser's js engine know anything about your **python** variables?

Comment: @DeepSpace this is written in Python

Comment: @Grass `driver.execute_script` executes javascript code using the browser's js engine. It has no idea what Python variables are defined

Comment: @BlackThunder error raised on `driver.execute_script("window.open(url);") #New tab`

Comment: @DeepSpace So, how to define them?

Comment: @Grass See my answer

Comment: Try: `driver.execute_script("window.open("+url+");")`

Comment: @BlackThunder - Can you recheck your comment are double quotes correct ?

Comment: @BlackThunder Got error: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` with your codes too..(used updated one..)

Comment: @BlackThunder your code should be `driver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"');")`, Grass this will work for you...

Comment: Whenever I open chrome from the selenium it also opens one tab ([see image](https://imgur.com/DfVcjya)), why it opens? How to stop that? (for the same codes..) @BlackThunder and all...

Comment: Can anyone please help me with: 1) [Chrome opens with “Data;” with selenium chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243080/chrome-opens-with-data-with-selenium-chromedriver) and 2) [Console Log/ cmd.exe not closing in chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236941/console-log-cmd-exe-not-closing-in-chromedriver)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because the **javascript** variable `url` is not defined.

`driver.execute_script` executes JS code using the browser's JS engine. It has no idea what Python variables are defined before `execute_script` was called.

Instead of hardcoding `url` you should use it as a variable:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('{}');".format(url))
```

Comment: Got Error: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: I forgot `' '`. I fixed my answer.

Comment: @DeepSpace - I also thinks it will work now. we need single quotes before '{ }'

Comment: Whenever I open chrome from the selenium it also opens one tab ([see image](https://imgur.com/DfVcjya)), why it opens? How to stop that? (for the same codes..)

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass Python variable to JavaScript. Try below:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('%s');" % url)
```

Comment: I've posted my answer before you made an edit. Your solution was incorrect. Also String substitution via `%s` works bit faster then via formatting... Of course it can hardly be noticed in this case :)

Comment: I never knew `%s` is faster than `{}`!! Thanks for the information sir.

Comment: @Topto , you can do `from timeit import timeit` and check how much time spend for `timeit('"some {} text".format("more")')` and for `timeit('"some %s text" % "more"')`... It's not a most precise way to check performance, but I got x20 faster result for `%s`