# Invalid Argument error while reading json values in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Invalid Argument error while reading external json file's values in python

I tried:

```
import json

with open('https://www.w3schools.com/js/json_demo.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    #for p in data['people']:
    print('Name: ' + data['name'])
```

Gave me error:

> with open('https://www.w3schools.com/js/json_demo.txt') as json_file: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
>   'https://www.w3schools.com/js/json_demo.txt'

Comment: `open` is for opening local files, not URLs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe then what to use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393324/in-python-given-a-url-to-a-text-file-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-read-the-cont

Comment: If you want to stick to the standard library, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/internet.html.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with: 1) [Chrome opens with “Data;” with selenium chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243080/chrome-opens-with-data-with-selenium-chromedriver) and 2) [Console Log/ cmd.exe not closing in chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236941/console-log-cmd-exe-not-closing-in-chromedriver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `open` is for opening local files, not URLs as commented by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) so, go with [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) as commented by [fl00r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298624/fl00r).

Though the link provided by him was for `python-2`

Try this (`python-3`):

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen('https://www.w3schools.com/js/json_demo.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    #for p in data['people']:
    print('Name: ' + data['name'])
```

> John

Answer (score 2):

Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.w3schools.com/js/json_demo.txt')
response.encoding = "utf-8-sig"
data = response.json()
print(data['name'])
>>> John
```